# need to hide the emitters light on the ground keeping the car's reflex

Tags: light, lighting, emission

[image]

hei everyone, i really need to find a way to not have the light's reflection and to keep the car's

Comment: Try the “light path” input node. You might be able to hide the light with that.

Comment: i'll try! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Glossy Ray" visibility from your light Object Properties:

[image: Glossy]

Comment: that would kinda work but i need the gloss reflection of the car to stay, so that's not the solution i'm looking for, i need to disable gloss reflections for the  ground plane only or isolate the car and it's shadow and render the bg in a new layer